# Facebook 'like' button - ASPX Master Pages

Tags: asp.net, facebook, master-pages, facebook-like

How do I add a FaceBook 'like' button to my master pages, does it need to be different for each page?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you wanting to tie into the Facebook API or do you just want similar functionality?

Comment: Looking to have a 'like' button so that people can send the link to their friends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Facebook Like Button generator here:

[Facebook Like Button Generator](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like)

Paste the generated iframe code into your master page.  If you leave it as is it will 'like' your site, not specific pages.

To 'like' the individual pages you can take the generated code and look for a section like this:

```
src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=mysite.com&amp;
```

Modify that to read:

```
src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<%=Request.Url.ToString() %>&amp;
```

And that should work to 'like' each specific page.

Comment: how can I also share links when click "Like" same as link you posted?

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand what you are trying to ask. Also, rather than a comment on this question, you are probably better off asking a new and detailed question. Very few people will see this comment and I may not know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should also add the META property of the generated facebook like button dynamically: use a `HtmlGenericControl` in the code behind. I wrote a full article how to add an asp.net like button while using master pages : [link text](http://www.smit.co.za/?p=8)